# group of order $p^n$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

If $p$ is any prime number and $G$ is a group of order $p^2$, then $G$ is abelian, and either $G\cong \mathbb Z_{p^2}$ or $G\cong \mathbb Z_p \times \mathbb Z_p$.

How about order $p^n$ where $n$ is any integer? Is there similar conclusion, i.e. If $p$ is any prime number, $n$ is an integer, and $G$ is a group of order $p^n$, then $G$ is abelian; either $G\cong \mathbb Z_{p^n}$ or $G=H \times K$, where $H$ and $K$ are subgroups of $G$, $H$ is a group of order $p^i$, $K$ is a group of order $p^j$ and $i+j=n$?

Comment: What does $G_{p^n}$ mean ? $(G/p^n G)$?

Comment: The word to search for is 'p-group'. No, there is no simple classification for general p-groups.

Comment: @Rick sorry for the confusion notation, question updated.

Comment: If that would be true, since poduct of Abelian groups is Abelian, a simple induction would show that every $p$-group is abelian.

Comment: Very much no. Once you get to $p^3$, you get nonabelian groups. You *can* bound what is called the “nilpotency class” (a group of order $p^n$ is nilpotent of class atm ost $n-2$), and for those of maximal class some structure is known. But they can be indecomposable (not a direct product of two groups) and/or nonabelian. Of course, they must nontrivial center.

Comment: As mentioned above, there is no general classification. However, there are cases like all groups of order $p^3$ are isomorphic to either the abelian groups or two classes of non-abelian groups namely $E_{p^3}$ or $M_{p^3}$. Similarly, some progress has been done up to groups of the type $p^7$ I guess.

Comment: In fact, classifying all $p$-groups is considered a very hard problem. “Most” groups are groups of order $2^n$ for some $n$. Even *counting* the number of nonisomorphic groups of order $p^n$ is hard: results are only known for $p=2$, $n\leq 10$, and $p\gt 2$, $n\leq 7$, if I remember correctly.

Comment: See [p-groups](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-group) for a summary of the previous comments and more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The classification of $p$-groups is considered a very hard problem. “Most” groups are $p$-groups, in a precise sense that would take too long to explain (in fact, it is conjectured that if you take the number of isomorphism classes of order $2^k\leq n$, and divide by the number of isomorphism classes of groups of order at most $n$, the limit as $n\to\infty$ will be $1$.)

A $p$-group must have nontrivial center. If $G$ is a $p$-group, we let $Z_0(G)=\{e\}$, and let $Z_{i+1}(G)$ be the subgroup of $G$ such that $Z_{i+1}(G)/Z_i(G)$ is the center of $G/Z_i(G)$. The least value of $c$ such that $Z_c(G)=G$ is called the “class of $G$” (so abelian groups are class $1$, center-by-abelian are class $2$, etc).

The coclass of a group of order $p^n$ is $n-c$. The analysis of $p$-groups by co-class is relatively recent, as these things go. They also informed a series of important conjectures about $p$-groups that, in a way, brought order out of the chaos.

The Co-class Theorems that give some unifying structure. The strongest one is:

> **Theorem.** There is a function $f(p,r)$ such that every finite $p$-group of coclass $r$ has a normal subgroup $K$ of class at most $2$ and index at most $f(p,r)$. If $p=2$, one may require $K$ to be abelian.

There is some work on the finer structure, but this gives you an idea of how far the state of the art is from something like what you were hoping for.

Comment: Can also check onto co-class conjectures and the work by Shalev Aner, if interested

Comment: Just to give an example illustrating how many groups of order $p^n$ there can be, even for small $n$, there are over ten million isomorphism classes of groups of order $2^9 = 512$, and nearly fifty billion of order $2^{10} = 1024$.